# Get two foreign key value from two table with join

Tags: sql, join, subquery, inner-join

I have tables below;

```
Course(cname, ccode, credit, dept) // course table.
Section(sno, ccode, semestr, year, prof); // course and lectures according to year and semester value.
Prerequisite(ccode, precode) // prerequisite for any course.
```

Question:

List course and prerequisite courses- code and name for both- that are opened in 2012

I try to solve it via join.

```
select c.ccode, c.cname, p.precode from Course as c 
inner join prerequisite as p on p.ccode=c.ccode;
```

The query returns tuples below.

```
Course | Name                 | Pre. code  
B201   | software engineering | B101  
B202   | operating system     | B101  
H202   | civil law            | H102
```

How can I get the name of prerequisite course's name and their codes?
The desired result must be below;

```
Course    | Name                 | Pre. code  | Pre. name
B201      | software engineering | B101       | aaaaa   
B202      | operating system     | B101       | aaaaa 
H202      | civil law            | H102       | bbbb
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your course and pre-requisite? Is there a many to one or many to many. Its better if you can post an image of the relationship

Comment: many-to-many, A course has more than one pre-requisite courses and A course is pre-requisite course for more than one courses. 
I have no ER diagram. The question is from my db exam.

Comment: for the name you need to join back to course on precode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use your query, and add an `EXISTS` clause.  Basically the logic is in the `EXISTS` clause, I found all courses that have section in 2012.  Then the `EXISTS` will only return courses that match the `EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT c.ccode, c.cname, p.precode 
FROM Course c 
JOIN prerequisite p ON p.ccode = c.ccode
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Section
    WHERE ccode = c.ccode AND year = '2012'
)
```

Or if using `JOIN`,

```
SELECT c.ccode, c.cname, p.precode, cp.cname
FROM Course c 
JOIN prerequisite p ON p.ccode = c.ccode
JOIN Course cp ON cp.ccode = p.precode
JOIN Section s ON s.ccode = c.ccode
WHERE s.year = '2012'
```

Comment: I got it. thanks. "Joining a table itself" is awesome. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.ccode, c.cname
     , p.precode, cp.name as preName 
  from Course as c 
  join prerequisite as p 
    on p.ccode = c.ccode 
  join Cource cp 
    on cp.ccode = p.precode
```

Comment: I have tried second join on prerequisite table to getting name. 
It works. thanks.